# Get result from mysql orderd by IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id IN (13, 15, 9, 27)
```

My result is:

```
invoice_id | invoice_number | ...
------------------------------------
9          | 201006003      |
13         | 201006020      |
15         | 201006022      |
27         | 201006035      |
```

which is the result set I want except that is ordered  by the invoice_id (which is an autoincrement value).

**Now I want the result in the order I specified in my query (13, 15, ...). Is there a way to achive that?**

The background is that I have a DataTable bound to a DataGridView. The user can filter and sort the result but if he want's to print the result I don't use the DataTable for printing because it only contains the most important columns and instead I pull the whole records from the database and pass it to my printing control.

I also tried to extend the existing DataTable with the missing results but that seems to slower than using the IN (...) query.

Comment: I don't think it's possible just using an orderby, but there are workarounds. Can you generate another query, or is orderby your only choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ugly, but you could do:

```
ORDER BY CASE invoice_id WHEN 13 THEN 0 WHEN 15 THEN 1 WHEN 9 THEN 2 WHEN 27 THEN 3 ELSE 4 END
```

Actually, there's the FIELD function:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(invoice_id, 13, 15, 9, 27)
```

The [FIELD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns the position of the first argument in the list of the rest.

Or, if you're generating it dynamically, you could do:

```
WHERE invoice_id IN ({list}) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(invoice_id, '{list}')
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the `FIELD` order by parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id IN (13, 15, 9, 27) ORDER BY FIELD (invoice_id, 13, 15, 9, 27)
```

Comment: thanks, ircmaxell was a few seconds faster but you deserve a upvote, too ;)